# How can i suppport both Unicode and Multi-Byte Character Set in my code?

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode, multibyte

i must say im new to win32 c++ programming so i face a problem that
some code compile in  Multi-Byte Character Set and not in Unicode Character Set.
how can my code support both ?
for example this NOT compiles in Multi-byte only in Unicode and the commented vector only in  MultiByte:

```
 //vector<char> str2(FullPathToExe.begin(), FullPathToExe.end());
 vector<wchar_t> str2(FullPathToExe.begin(), FullPathToExe.end());

    str2.push_back('\0');
    if (!CreateProcess(NULL,
                     &str2[0],
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    TRUE,
                    0,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    &si,
                    &pi))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`TCHAR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#TCHAR) as the character type (e.g. `std::vector<TCHAR>`), which is:

> A `WCHAR` if `UNICODE` is defined, a `CHAR`
>   otherwise.
>
> This type is declared in WinNT.h as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> #ifdef UNICODE
>    typedef WCHAR TCHAR;
> #else
>    typedef char TCHAR;
> #endif
> ```

Comment: where to use it in the vector?

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to support both, unless your application must support Windows Mobile or desktop version like Windows 95 or older.

If you write for current desktop or server Windows, supporting "Unicode" is enough. Just go for `wchar_t`!

Answer (score 1):

By "new to Win32 C++ programming", I'm assume you mean you *don't* have an existing large program using "ANSI" strings that you need to maintain.  If so, then why do you *want* to build an "ANSI" version?  Just do everything with `wchar_t`.

```
vector<wchar_t> str2(FullPathToExe.begin(), FullPathToExe.end());

str2.push_back(L'\0');      // Note the prefix.
if (!CreateProcessW(NULL,   // Note the W; explicit is better than implicit.
                    &str2[0],
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    TRUE,
                    0,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    &si,
                    &pi))
```

If you need to work with multi-byte strings (e.g., for reading files, or for working with third-party libraries that use `char` rather than `wchar_t`), then convert them using [`WideCharToMultiByte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the macros/typedefs provided by microsoft and add your own, to support both.

```
TCHAR -> typedef to char/wchar_t
_TEXT() -> creates a text constant either wide or multibyte _TEXT("hallo")
```

Probably  usefull to add so you could use a String class instead of a vector for text manipulations:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
   typedef std::wstring String;
#else
   typedef std::string String;
#endif
```

Comment: Why not just `typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> String;`?

Comment: @Georg this is even shorter shorter. nice!